# ng-table params.page doesnt get reset to 1 if a filter is applied

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

When a filter is applied, ng-table doesnt reset the page to 1 automatically, is it expected ? In the samples that I saw, the page number gets reset when a filter changes without any additional code/config. As a result if the number of filtered rows is less than current page * records per page, the table is empty.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle or post your code?

Comment: Yes after filter this should start from page 1.

Comment: code snippet below function getData($defer, params) {
 $http.get( BASE_URL, { params.url() } )
  .success(function(response) {
   params.total(response.total);
   $defer.resolve(response.result);
 });